# How can I make too many properties readable in module pattern and is there any alternative

Tags: javascript

Here is a module let say,

```
var UI = UI || {};
UI.Old = {
  v1: "",
  v2: "",
  v3: [],
  v4: 0,
  v5: "",
  v6: "",
  v7: "xxxx",
  v8: "",
  v9: "",
  v10: "",

  init: function(options) {
    this.v1 = options.v1;
    this.v10 ... and so on

    this.showLatestTime(new Date().getSeconds())
  },
  showLatestTime: function(time) {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = time;
  }
};
```

Is there any way I could hide these variables and make them more readable ?

Comment: When it comes unreadable it's more then enough.

Comment: @scriptmonster I updated my question

Comment: You can have `props` or `attr` which will be an object of all such keys. Idea is to group similar items like if they are associated to UI flags, you can have `obj.UI.flags.myFlag`, if they are status, then something like `obj.UI.status.myStatus`. Also, you should not return everything. You should try to return which are necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a object with all options and use an extend function

```js
(function (root) {
    root.extend = function (obj) {
        var source, prop;
        for (var i = 1, length = arguments.length; i < length; i++) {
            source = arguments[i];
            for (prop in source) {
                if (hasOwnProperty.call(source, prop)) {
                    obj[prop] = source[prop];
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    };

})(window);

var UI = UI || {};
UI.Old = {
  settings:{
 v1: "",
  v2: "",
  v3: [],
  v4: 0,
  v5: "",
  v6: "",
  v7: "xxxx",
  v8: "",
  v9: "",
  v10: ""
  },
  init: function(options) {
    this.settings = extend(this.settings,options);

   // this.showLatestTime(new Date().getSeconds())
  },
  showLatestTime: function(time) {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = time;
  },
  showSettings:function(){
    console.log(this.settings)
  }
};


UI.Old.init({
  v1:"test1",v2:"test2",v3:[1,2,3],v10:"123"
});
UI.Old.showSettings();
```